# what happens if I try to send my gdax btc to an eth address?

Tags: exchanges, address.transfer, gdax

My question is about transferring btc to and eth address by accident?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this kind of mistake is possible. Bitcoin addresses are represented by ~34-character base-58 strings, while Ethereum addresses are represented by 40-character base-16 strings.

Comment: interesting because I tried to send GDAX btc to eth address on cryptopia but gdax said it was an incorrect btc address and then when I tried to send it to the actual cryptopia btc it said i did not have enough funds

Comment: My guess is that the two are unrelated. I would investigate what's causing the message about insufficient funds.

Comment: it happened right after I clicked the transfer button and then right after that my funds showed zero and my history shows a transaction of the exact amount and the transaction being completed

Comment: Ah. Then I would contact GDAX support and ask them. Sounds like a possible bug in their side, but my guess is still that no funds were transferred.

Comment: Im hoping your guess is right, i might be refunded the funds once it figures out its not the right address or it could be that the btc funds are taking a long time to transfer. after all I have only waited like an hour maybe